# Cloud storage options for vector data in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, storage

I am familiar with hosting raster images in the cloud using services like AWS S3 and Google Cloud Storage, where they can be served as Cloud Optimized GeoTIFFs (COGs) in GeoServer. However, I am now exploring the possibility of using cloud storage as a location for vector files to be ingested into GeoServer.

Currently, the vector files are located in the same machine the geoserver is deployed. I want to eliminate the task of shutting down the server to update data files in the machine.

Is it feasible to configure cloud storage, such as AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage, as a source for vector files in GeoServer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it will be very slow. A better solution would be to use a cloud based PostGIS datastore (such as RDS on AWS or similar on Azure etc).

Comment: Thank you! Can u GeoWebCache help in improving performance such as loading?

Comment: That solves a different problem